# RSS feed link on archives page not working

Tags: permalinks, rss

I am trying to add a RSS link on my website archive-pages, which means,
Suppose I am on page `http://mbas.in/location/mba-in-usa/` then on this page, I will be having a **RSS LINK** named link, when I click on this link, it should redirect me to `http://mbas.in/location/mba-in-usa/feed`

When anyone navigates through my archive-pages, they will get RSS FEED OF THAT PAGE just by clicking one link,

for this I tried the following code

`<a href="<?php get_permalink(); ?>/feed">RSS feed of this page</a>`

but I am not getting that, instead its giving me `http://mbas.in/feed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a mess of this in comments, so will start from scratch.

The feed links for archive pages are usually only outputted for browser detection by `feed_links_extra()`.

From looking at its source there is number of different function to get link for the archive pages:

- `get_category_feed_link( $cat_id )`;
- `get_tag_feed_link( $tag_id )`;
- `get_term_feed_link( $term_id, $taxonomy )` (this one I found separately, not currently used in automatic feed links).

So catch-all archive feed link that will work for any taxonomy (including categories and terms) can be built like this:

```
function archive_feed_link() {

    if( is_archive() ) {

        global $wp_query;

        $taxonomy = $wp_query->get_queried_object();

        return get_term_feed_link( $taxonomy->term_id, $taxonomy->taxonomy );
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, I tried that also, but instead of giving me that archives-page feed link, it is giving me that archives page first post feed link, 
You can check the output on this page http://mbas.in/location/mba-in-usa/

Just above the google ad, see this link `RSS feed of this page`

Comment: Ah missed that, if it's archive than permalink makes no sense. Tried  `the_feed_link('feed');` or `echo get_feed_link();`?

Comment: @Rarst I tried it, but its giving me the homepages feed, even for `echo get_feed_link`, that is also returning homepages feed url

Comment: @ntechi sorry, looked at the wrong function. Try [`get_category_feed_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_feed_link), only works for categories, there is analogue for tags `get_tag_feed_link()`.

Comment: @Rarst both I tried, its returning me with some weird URL
check this
`http://mbas.in/location/mba-in-usa/%3Cbr%20/%3E%20%3Cb%3EWarning%3C/b%3E:%20%20Missing%20argument%201%20for%20get_category_feed_link%28%29,%20called%20in%20/home/managem3/public_html/mbas/wp-content/themes/cityguide/archive.php%20on%20line%2010%20and%20defined%20in%20%3Cb%3E/home/managem3/public_html/mbas/wp-includes/link-template.php%3C/b%3E%20on%20line%20%3Cb%3E570%3C/b%3E%3Cbr/%3E`

Comment: @ntechi see documentation for the function, I linked to it.

Comment: @Rarst this is for category, I am having Custom taxonomies, If you see my URL structure `http://mbas.in/location/mba-in-usa`
so `mba-in-usa` is not category, its custom taxonomies term.